# how to set the value of array into a input field with php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array

```
$texts = [ "maybank2u.com",
           "Open BillPayment", 
           "Status: Successful", 
           "Reference number 2950211545", 
           "Transaction date: 01 Feb 2016 13:09:17", 
           "Amount: RM100.00", 
           "From Account 564155051577 WCAa" ]
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($texts as $row =>$value): ?> 
                <li><h3> <?php echo ucfirst($value) ?></h3></li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
         <label>Status:</label><input type="text" name="status" value="" id="status"><br>

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586101/how-to-put-a-php-array-of-strings-into-html-input-fields) but it's not working in my case. I want to set the value of `$value` into the input field

Comment: You have multiple values and only one `<input>`. Which `$value` do you want to insert there? The `"Status: Successful"` one? So you end up with `value="successful"`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I Want to insert `"Status: Successful"` into the input field

Comment: <input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo ($texts[2]) ?>" id="status"><br> is it a good solutions?

Comment: on what basis you want status: successful?

Answer (score 0):

Try This --

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($texts as $row =>$value): ?> 
            <li><h3> <?php echo ucfirst($value) ?></h3></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
     <label>Status:</label>

     <input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo ucfirst($texts[2]) ?>" id="status"><br>

</div>
```

Comment: what if I only want to set `"Status: Successful"` into the input field?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo ($texts[2]) ?>" id="status"><br>`
is it a good solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($texts as $row =>$value): ?> 
                <li><h3> <?php echo ucfirst($value) ?></h3></li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
         <label>Status:</label><input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo $texts[2] ?>" id="status"><br>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use index for your array:

```
<?php
$texts = [ 
//...
           "status": "Successful", 
           "reference_number": "2950211545", 
           "transaction_date": "01 Feb 2016 13:09:17", 
           "amount": "RM100.00", 
           "from_account": "564155051577 WCAa" 
]
?>
```

Then:

`<input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo $texts['status'] ?>" id="status">`